# Передача данных из файла по rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

Коллеги, имеется ситуация: на сервер передаются логи, которых сохраняются rsyslog`ом в файл.
Необходимо данные из этого файла передать по сислогу на другой сервер. 
Как передать данные из файла по сислогу?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не из файла надо, а ещё одно правило rsyslog'у, на отправку логов дальше. Если не изменяет память мне, то как то так:

```
*.info  /var/log/info
*.info  action(type="omfwd" target="192.0.0.192" protocol="tcp")
```